# Update product to Magento in multiple stores using python API

Tags: magento, odoo

I am trying to export product to Magento in two different stores say 'shop1' and 'shop2'. first i have exported product to shop1 and then again same product to shop2. But when i export product to shop2 it removes product from shop1. I want the product available in both the shops.

Comment: Are you exporting the Products from Magento or Importing the Products in it? And which service you are using SOAP/REST.

Comment: In magento you do not need to import same product to different stores you just have to assign products to multiple stores. You can do this by assigning website to product.

Comment: @ROBIN: I am exporting products from odoo to Magento

Comment: @gulshan maurya:If i assigned both websites to products at the time of API call it updates the product in both the websites but i have to send product along with different prices for different stores

Comment: To set website wise prices first you have to make price scope 'Website' from System > Configuration. And you can import prices per website using csv after product get imported successfully.

Comment: Yes, i have set the scope prices per website. I am not using CSV to import prices in Magento. I am exporting prices along with product from Odoo using 'ol_catalog_product.update' API call. Here is data dict with some fields i am sending with API call
{'status': u'1'
msrp_enabled': False
type_id': u'simple'
cost': 3525.89
special_from_date': False
category_ids': [u'2', u'2', u'694', u'3']
tax_class_id': u'2'
price': 3596.41
custom_design_from': False
visibility': u'4'
manufacturer': u'10'
name': <product name here>
websites': [u'1']
special_to_date': False
msrp': 0.0}